# SSRS on load redirect

Tags: redirect, reporting-services

I'm trying to make a very simple report that on load it redirects automatically to another URL but it seem to be not easy as I tought, mostly because I can't find a load report event, and because I can't use javascript in my custom-code.

What is the Best/Simplest way to make a dummy SSRS report that on load redirects to a certain URL?

Comment: You're asking for a capability that is not part of any SSRS use case, so I'd be surprised if there is an answer that meets your needs.

Comment: Agree with @BrianDriscoll. SSRS is a reporting tool. The user would have to get results then click on a URL to get directed to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is not what you want but close.

Create a text box in the report that says 'Click here to load the next report'

1. right click on it
2. select text box properties
3. Actions
4. Go to report
5. Follow the prompts...